# Google PeopleApi - CreateContact method invalid argument

Tags: node.js, express, google-api, google-people-api

I'm trying to create a contact from my application and documentation is hideous!

i build a contact object from data i receive by form

```
var contact = {
  names: [
    {
      displayName: body.name
    }
  ],
  phoneNumbers: [
    {
      value: body.phone
    }
  ],
  biographies: [
    {
      value: body.notes
    }
  ],
  userDefined: [
  {
      value: body.snif
    },
    {
      value: body.position
    },
    {
      value: body.sms
    },
    {
      value: body.whatsapp
    }
  ]
};
```

and try to make the request but i can't figure out what's wrong

```
const service = google.people({version: 'v1', auth});
service.people.createContact({
    parent: 'people/me', 
    resource: contact
}, {}, function(err, res) {
    console.log(err)
});
```

and i get 400 INVALID_ARGUMENTS

```
errors:
[ { message: 'Request contains an invalid argument.',
   domain: 'global',
   reason: 'badRequest' } ] };
```

Nodejs, ExpressJs

please what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- The reason of error is to be not keys for values. For property of `userDefined`, please add a property of `key`.

  - By this, you can retrieve the value using the key.

#### Modified script:

Please modify `userDefined` as follows. These are sample keys. So please modify them for your situation.

```
userDefined: [
  {
    value: body.snif,
    key: "snif", // Added
  },
  {
    value: body.position,
    key: "position", // Added
  },
  {
    value: body.sms,
    key: "sms", // Added
  },
  {
    value: body.whatsapp,
    key: "whatsapp", // Added
  },
],
```

Also if you want to retrieve the response from API, how about modifying as follows?

```
service.people.createContact({
  parent: 'people/me',
  resource: contact,
}, {}, function(err, res) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err.errors);
      return;
    }
    console.log(res.data);
});
```

#### Note:

- This modified script supposes that you can use the API and scopes for creating contacts.

#### References:

- [people.createContact](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/createContact)
- [Resource: people](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people#Person)

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. adding the Keys to userDefined didn't do anything. More over deleting all fields and leaving only names raises the same error.
also the function that does the api request doesn't require any param. so it should be ok (unless it's invalid). still don't understand what am i doing wrong. thank you for you answer

Comment: turn out your answer was partially correct. Not giving key values to userDefined does raise INVALID_ARGUMENT. Another problem i had is giving displayName in names which is read_only field. any other should be ok. Once i gave the name as "givenName" instead of "displayName" i got the desired 200 code.

Comment: @FedeSc Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.